# Get the closest comment node in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Simplification :

I have an HTML structure :

```
 <!-- remark  data-foo="5" -->

  <div>
     <div>
        <div>
            <input class='btn' value='click me' type='button'/>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>

   <!-- remark  data-foo="6" -->

  <div>
        <div>
            <input class='btn' value='click me' type='button'/>
       </div>
  </div>
```

How can I access the closest comment element when clicking a button ?

In other words :

When user click the first button , code should access the first remark element.

When user click the second button , code should access the second remark element.

Sure, it's easy to access the access parents via `closest` / `parents`.
But this will only provide the parents. I need to access the parent prev sibling.

[**JSBIN**](https://jsbin.com/newiyozuri/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: You'd have to select the div that has the comment node as a sibling and use `.prev()` or something

Comment: Is the depth in terms of divs variable as your example shows?

Comment: @j08691 it is dynamic...That's why I've written 2 & 3 depth inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
$(".btn").on('click',function (){

  var element = this;
  var comment = null;
  while(element) {
    comment = document.evaluate("./preceding-sibling::comment()", element).iterateNext();
    if(comment) {
      break;
    }
    element = element.parentNode;
  }
  if(comment) {
    alert(comment.textContent);
  } else {
    alert("No comment found");
  }

});
```

It works for an arbitrary depth and always selects the nearest comment node above the element.

EDIT: Same solution using jQuery `.contents()` instead of `document.evaluate()`:

```
$(".btn").on('click',function (){

  var element = this;
  var comment = null;
  while(element && element.parentNode) {
    var children = $(element.parentNode).contents();
    for(var i = children.index(element) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if(children[i].nodeType === 8) {
        comment = children[i];
        break;
      }
    }
    if(comment) {
      break;
    }
    element = element.parentNode;
  }
  if(comment) {
    alert(comment.textContent);
  } else {
    alert("No comment found");
  }

});
```

Comment: Truly nice. Short question : does the `iterateNext`  calculated again and again each loop cycle ??

Comment: The XPath is being calculated relative to a different element each time the loop cycles. Each time, `iterateNext` is running against a different query, so it gets the first result of the query and exits the loop if a comment was found.

Comment: Truly nice & elegant solution. Thanks.

Comment: See my edit - it uses jQuery instead of document.evaluate, but the logic is otherwise the same.